# Android Programming Beginning

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-debug

I am a beginner to Android programming. I install all required software to develop apps. My system is Windows 7 64bit with 8G ram. I started with a simple **"hello world"** application.

But it takes too long to launch the Android system on emulator, and sometimes I am tired of waiting and stop it, and if it finally launch it shows an Error message

> unfortunately launcher has stop working!

frequently on android screen and does not show any key on android home screen.

Is my system's RAM is too small for android programming? If so what is minimum requirement?

And also I have an android phone, is there any way to test and debug my Android programs using my phone so I don't have to increase my system's RAM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recent changes to Google's AVD have made Android SDK Virtual machines very usable. if you're experiencing slow down make sure you have most recent HAXM from intel. Note is only compatible with intel processors. I would suggest to make sure virtualization is turned on in your BIOS.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html

if you were using a Linux machine be sure to install KVM Kernel-based Virtualization Machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I update SDK and install HAXM and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your system ram is more than sufficient for android development.
Download the latest version of Android Studio and Android SDK.
Open Android Sdk and install x86 or x86_64 emulator if you have an intel machine and also install haxm accelerator this will provide you with huge performance boost.

If you want to debug with your phone, open settings->developer options and enable adb and then run the app on your phone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I update SDK and install HAXM and it works.